# How to sync authentification between Frontend, Backend and API?

Tags: php, security

I have a CodeIgniter App that is made of 3 parts:

- The API, basically is a separate entity, with its own location
- The CodeIgniter back-end that renders the pages
- The FrontEnd of the app, mostly jQuery.

I have a login system based on session and cookies. Basically the authentification data is stored on the client (browser).

A user authentificates with email and password. The backend looks for a authentification cookie and knows if it is logged in or not. If I make an AJAX request to the API directly, the API also knows if the user is authentificated.

Problem: I want to render some data server-side (That means I need to make a call to the API from the backend. It's a server to server communication. They are located on the same machine. ).

The API tells the backend that it's not authentificated, because obviously no cookie is set on the backend.

How do you pass authentification data from backend to api?

I might pass the userID via a secure endpoint that can be accessed only via the server to server communication, but I don't like the idea.

Any solutions to this? I read about oAuth and JWT but don't understand how they might help me.

Answer (score 0):

the API should be built on top of the back-end. meaning the request is handled by API, then activates a function in the back-end and sends a response back to the client who sent the request(according to the result of the function in the back end). JWT json web token, is a token provider which means once you log in you get back a token "string" that is stored in the data base, in the request for the API you add the token to the header named Authorization instead of sending user and password everytime and you can extract the user info out of the token itself.but still there is need to check the validity of user and pass somehow at the first time. 
basically you should send from client to API, API to server and then for response server to API and API to client. by server i mean back-end.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. It might work, but the downside is that it requires a lot of changes in the architecture.